# How to create a 'dot function'? (js objects?)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
Document.prototype.greenify = function(){
    return {
        style : function(){
            return this.color = "green";
        }
    }
};
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].greenify();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey out there,

I wanna build a 'dot function'.
My function for trial should 'greenify' my element.
I already tried to add the function to Window- object but I came to the same result. 
So, now my question...
What I did wrong or did I forget something?
I'm thankfully for each answer I receive :)

Comment: By "dot function" do you mean a method? You need to add it to the prototype of the objects you'll be invoking it on, but adding to someone else's prototype (even the browser's) is a Bad Idea.

Comment: ... please don't do this. Add a function `greenify()`, which accepts a HTML element, and do that instead.

Comment: Despite this can be done, I totally agree with Matt. Of course it's matter of opinions, but take a look at this article: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ .. I would rather recommend you to make your own little "object" to deal with such things instead.

Comment: @briosheje It's not a matter of opinion, it's actually dangerous on the grounds that a variable or library can be set up with a no-collision option, but that's not practical if you are extending someone's prototype. Depending on the implementation, you may also run into unusual prototypes around native objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`h1` elements don't inherit from `Document.prototype`. They inherit from those:

- `HTMLHeadingElement.prototype`
- `HTMLElement.prototype`
- `Element.prototype`
- `Node.prototype`
- `EventTarget.prototype`
- `Object.prototype`

For example, you can add the method to `HTMLElement.prototype`:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.greenify = function(){
    this.style.color = "green";
};
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].greenify();
```

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.greenify = function(){
    this.style.color = "green";
};
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].greenify();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, note that modifying objects you don't own is considered a bad practice.

Comment: Note that adding to a prototype not under your control, especially a native one, is bad practice and may cause collisions with other libraries. You should avoid it whenever possible. This answer is correct, however, so no dv.

Comment: Thank you very much I already tried it from the beginning of the week. :)